# How to make a DropDownListFor not selectable in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my View in Razor I use a DroDownList I would like to have this control not Selectable. How to do it, (please post a sample)?

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CandidateId, Model.CandidatesList)
    </div>
```

Comment: This may sound silly, but why make it a dropdownlist if you don't want it selectable?

Comment: it is for an DETAILS view, I would like to leave the same control as in edit (a drop down list) but make it possible that is not selectable.

Comment: could you please post a sample of code using razor? it is my firsst time I write some razor code thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the `disabled` attribute with values of true and false.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CandidateId, Model.CandidatesList, new { disabled = "true" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably want to look at the override for DropDownListFor which take a dictionary of HTML attributes and perhaps pass something like 'disabled = "true"' through.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703436(v=vs.108).aspx

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CandidateId, Model.CandidatesList, new { disabled = "true" })
    </div>
```

Comment: no need to use @ since `disabled` is not a C# keyword unlike `class` where we do need to add it otherwise we wouldn't be able to provide class attribute to our elements.

Comment: Thanks @RobertKoritnik I hadn't run the code, just suggesting an approach, have updated the answer, ta.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CandidateId, Model.CandidatesList, 
                       new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.CandidateId,
    Model.CandidatesList,
    new { @disabled = "disabled" }
)
```

But you can not get the dropdown value in controller after submission. You can use a hidden field for setting the dropdown value.